# Spread object into Map in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

Using TypeScript, is it possible to type the following Map more acurately?

```
export const animalsMap = new Map<AnimalIdsEnum, object>([
    [
        AnimalIdsEnum.sylvester,
        {
            id: AnimalIdsEnum.sylvester,
            ...new CatAnimalData("Sylvester", "Tweety");
        }
    ],
    [
        AnimalIdsEnum.tweety,
        {
            id: AnimalIdsEnum.tweety,
            ...new BirdAnimalData("Tweety", "Sylvester");
        },
    ],
]);
```

Where:

```
export class AbstractAnimalData {

    name:string,
}

export class CatAnimalData extends AbstractAnimalData {

    favouriteFood:string,
    // NB: Leaving out the constructor for brevity
}

export class BirdAnimalData extends AbstractAnimalData {
    
    archEnemy:string,
    // NB: Leaving out the constructor for brevity
}
```

Basically, this map structure is very convenient to use in practice, but I am not sure if it is possible to get it typed more accurately, given that:

- I am spreading the animal data into the map
- The value part of the map is the id plus the animal data (so more than just the XAnimalData type)

---

Note: In practice, the objects created by `new CatAnimalData("Sylvester", "Tweety");` and `new BirdAnimalData("Tweety", "Sylvester");` are imported from separate files. For convenience and clarity, I do not want to assign the id keys in those files, but only in the Map.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, for instance there is no `AnimalIdsEnum`. Apart from that, please comment what behavior are you expect

Comment: spread syntax only copies enumerable own properties, so using it on classes may not have the result you expect.

Comment: As per the above comment, so long as none of your classes have methods (which are not enumerable own properties) you can use `new Map < AnimalIdsEnum, { id: AnimalIdsEnum } & (BirdAnimalData | CatAnimalData) >` [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBkGVm) but you should probably either add the `id` to the instance itself, or store the animal instance in its own property `{ id: AnimalIdsEnum.sylvester, animal: new CatAnimalData("Sylvester", "Tweety")}` [playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2a79W)

Comment: @pilchard Thank you, this is very helpful. I am wondering though, is there no way to get the best of both worlds? I do see the advantage of being able to support methods (as per your second example), but I don't want to have to type an extra `.animal` every time I use this.

Comment: It depends on what role the `id` is playing, but it strikes me that this should probably be assigned to the instance. But if `name` is unique then id becomes redundant.

Comment: @pilchard `name` is not unique. `id` is unique. Logically speaking, I agree that `id` should be part of the instance (part of AbstractAnimalData). However, in practice, it is a lot more convenient to assign `id` in the same place in which the Map gets created.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question, which may provide more context regarding what I am trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72329070/branch-off-based-on-the-type-of-an-object

Comment: @Ben Just put the `id` in `AbstractAnimalData` (and make the constructors accept one)? Alternatively, don't use spread syntax, but `Object.assign(new BirdAnimalData("Tweety", "Sylvester"), {id: AnimalIdsEnum.tweety})`

Comment: @Bergi What is the difference between using `Object.assign()` and using `...` ? Wouldn't `Object.assign()` also only copy the object's enumerable own properties?

Comment: @Ben An object literal with spread syntax always creates a plain object. `Object.assign` copies the property values onto the first argument and returns that.