# Branch off based on the type of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

In TypeScript, how can I check the type of an object, and branch off based on that type?

```
const createAnimalForId(animalId: AnimalIdsEnum): CatAnimal | BirdAnimal {

    // animalData has type: CatAnimalData | BirdAnimalData | undefined
    const animalData = animalsMap.get(animalId);
  
    // Q: How can I check the type here?
    if(animalData "is of type" CatAnimalData) {
         // NB: I want it to be aware that animalData here is of type CatAnimalData
        return new CatAnimal(animalData);
    }

    // Q: How can I check the type here?
    else if(animalData "is of type" BirdAnimalData) {
        // NB: I want it to be aware that animalData here is of type BirdAnimalData
        return new BirdAnimal(animalData);
    }

    else {
        throw new RangeError("Animal type not recognised");
    }
}
```

NB: `CatAnimal` and `BirdAnimal` both inherit from `AbstractAnimal`.

Comment: can you show `CatAnimalData ` and `BirdAnimalData `

Comment: @HeetVakharia Sure, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328043/spread-object-into-map-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment127779505_72328043

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript at all, however, is there runtime type in Typescript? I think no. Isn't it translated to JS before running?

Comment: I just started again with TypeScript after a long break, so I'm not quite sure. But I understand it to be translated to JS first before running, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I check the type of an object?

Since these types are implemented as `class`es, you can just use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
if (animalData instanceof CatAnimalData) {
     …
}
if (animalData instanceof BirdAnimalData) {
    …
}
```

> … and branch off based on that type?

Don't. This is an ugly, non-extensible design. Instead, make all your inputs implement a `toAnimal` or `getAnimal` or `createAnimal` method, and then just call that:

```
export class AbstractAnimalData {
    name: string;
    abstract createAnimal(): Animal {
        throw new RangeError("Animal type not recognised");
    }
}

export class CatAnimalData extends AbstractAnimalData {
    favouriteFood: string;
    // NB: Leaving out the constructor for brevity
    createAnimal(): CatAnimal {
        return new CatAnimal(this);
    }
}

export class BirdAnimalData extends AbstractAnimalData {
    archEnemy: string;
    // NB: Leaving out the constructor for brevity
    createAnimal: BirdAnimal {
        return new BirdAnimal(animalData);
    }
}
```

then

```
function createAnimalForId(animalId: AnimalIdsEnum): Animal {
    const animalData = animalsMap.get(animalId);
    if (!animalData) {
        throw new RangeError(`AnimalId '${animalId}' not supported`);
    }
    return animalData.createAnimal();
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if property in exists in `animalType`

```js
const createAnimalForId(animalId: AnimalIdsEnum): CatAnimal | BirdAnimal {

    // animalData has type: CatAnimalData | BirdAnimalData | undefined
    const animalData = animalsMap.get(animalId);
  
    
    if('favouriteFood' in animalData) {
         // CatAnimalData
        return new CatAnimal(animalData);
    }

   
    else if("archEnemy" in animalData) {
        //BirdAnimalData
        return new BirdAnimal(animalData);
    }

    else {
        throw new RangeError("Animal type not recognised");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is basically the same as my answer, i.e. within the conditional cases, TypeScript won't be aware of the specific type of `animalData`.

Comment: I think TS will know as that property only exists in that type. so in vscode u would also get autocomplete accordingly

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of would be the following. However, this has the problem that, within the conditional cases, TypeScript is not aware of the specific type of `animalData`.

As far as I understand, this means I would have to manually cast it, which I don't think is ideal.

```
const createAnimalForId(animalId: AnimalIdsEnum): CatAnimal | BirdAnimal {

    // animalData has type: CatAnimalData | BirdAnimalData | undefined
    const animalData = animalsMap.get(animalId);
  
    if(animalData.type === animalType.catAnimal) {
         // Problem: TypeScript is not aware of the specific type of animalData here
        return new CatAnimal(
            animalData // as CatAnimalData
        ); 
    }

    else if(animalData.type === animalType.birdAnimal) {
        // NB: I want it to be aware that animalData here is of type BirdAnimalData
        return new BirdAnimal(
            animalData // as BirdAnimalData
        );
    }

    else {
        throw new RangeError("Animal type not recognised");
    }
}
```

Comment: "*within the conditional cases, TypeScript is not aware of the specific type of `animalData`*" - actually, it should be, assuming that `animalType` is an enum and the individual `AnimalData` variants contain a specific `type` field, so that the union becomes a tagged union

Comment: @Bergi `animalType` is an enum, yes. The individual `AnimalData` variants do not contain a `type` field. Instead, the `AbstractAnimalData` contains a field `type: AnimalType | undefined;`. This field is then assigned in the `constructor` of the individual `AnimalData` variants, e.g. `this.type = AnimalType.catAnimal`.

Comment: If I mouse-over `animalData` in the individual conditional cases, VSCode shows the type as  `BirdAnimalData | CatAnimalData`, i.e. it doesn't know.

Comment: Add `type: AnimalType.catAnimal` in `CatAnimalData` and add `type: AnimalType.birdAnimal` in `BirdAnimalData` and it'll work

Comment: @Bergi That appears to work. Can you explain why? What is the difference between having `type: AnimalType | undefined` in the parent class, versus having `type: AnimalType.catAnimal` in the child class? The syntax seems odd, assigning the enum's value as the property's data type using `:` (instead of assigning it as the property's value using `=`)? I also noticed that I then still have to set `this.type = AnimalType.catAnimal` in the child class constructor - otherwise I get an error: "Property 'type' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

Comment: It's not the enum's value, it's the enum value's type. You could also use a constant literal type. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions for the explanation. As for setting the value, yes you either need to do that in the constructor or in the field initialiser.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `instanceof` type guard:

```js
const createAnimalForId(animalId: AnimalIdsEnum): CatAnimal | BirdAnimal {

    // animalData has type: CatAnimalData | BirdAnimalData | undefined
    const animalData = animalsMap.get(animalId);
  
    if(animalData instanceof CatAnimalData) {
        // animalData here is of type CatAnimalData
        return new CatAnimal(animalData);
    }

    else if(animalData instanceof BirdAnimalData) {
        // animalData here is of type BirdAnimalData
        return new BirdAnimal(animalData);
    }

    else {
        throw new RangeError("Animal type not recognised");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried. Using `instanceof`, VSCode indeed shows the correct type in the conditional cases. However, at runtime, it goes straight into the `else` case and shows the error. I think it is because of the inheritance, but I am not sure.